# Page layout in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make one page scroll. Nav bar. Then a full width picture. than about me page, porfolio / projects and contact me. But it seems like am doing something wrong with the layout. Please help.

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#btnnavbar {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#btnhome {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
#imgbrand {
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: px;
  height: 220px;
  width: 280px;
}
#firstpage {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
.fixed-bg {
  /* The background image */
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/ekilja01/image/upload/v1478095932/DeathtoStock_Lonely_Commute-05_ricqva.jpg");
  /* Scale the background image to be as large as possible */
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar style available in Bootstrap framework-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- /end-->
    <!-- Anything that has to be responsive we are going to keep inside the Bootstrap grid -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- /end -->
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="btnnavbar">
          <!-- For screen readers only -->
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <!-- /end -->
          <!-- Hamburger menu button appears when browser window has been shrinked -->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- /end -->
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://codepen.io/ekilja01">
          <img class="img-responsive" id="imgbrand" src="http://www.kiljakandweb.com/favicon.png" alt="brand logo">
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li id="btnhome"><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="fixed-bg">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-center">1.4.1.3</h1>
        <p>fafafa</p>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
          <h1>Code</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have numerous unclosed tags. Run your code through a validator

Comment: I replicated your code [here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/YpKpNg). Looks fine, can you be more specific on what is going wrong ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa It is not, see Code on the top-middle of the page. It should be second page. there is even a text above that.

Comment: thanks @Turnip ... @Edgar - I have formatted your faulty HTML and added a `margin-top` to your `fixed-bg` div. Where do you want your "row"(which has Code in it) to be ? - inside the fixedbg or outside ? Check the codepen for updated

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa outside. So picture will be first page down after navbar, then second page starting with a word code

Comment: Second page ? You mean section ? - you need the "Code" section to be below the fixed bg section ?

Comment: Yes I mean section! Thats correct, new section, code div below the fixed bg section

Comment: Check the updated Codepen, firstly you cannot give 100% of height/min-height to the fixedbg and expect any div to be under that. So instead give a **"fixed" height(500px or so)** and then position that "code" section below it by one the 2 ways - give margin top equal to the height of the fixedbg OR use `position: absolute` and place it below. Check the Codepen for how it can be achieved

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I want to have fixed bg with parralax as a first page, then code its completely new section below that pic, with different backgdound, how can I achieve that? Because at the moment Code still with that background. I want something like this: http://codepen.io/andrewchar/full/NxLeje

Comment: Yes in that case you need to make the **background image fixed** not the div as fixed. I could show you how to do that updating the codepen.? If you want parallax then your current approach won't work.